# Is it possible to use NHibernate 3 with current release of Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, castle-activerecord, linq-to-nhibernate, castle

I need to use new LINQ provider in NHibernate 3.0 using Castle ActiveRecord. How it possible. Can I simply replace NHibernate 3.0 assembly with that one that comes with Castle ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

It was [discussed](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/d2ff6d1af4d4d1f8) a couple of months ago. In a nutshell, it's not trivial, but it shouldn't be too hard either. As far as I know nobody's actively working on this (I don't see any "NH3" [branches/forks in github](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/network)), it would be great if you can, but I'd confirm first on the [Castle dev list](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel).

Comment: Good idea to do it myself. But I'm not a master of NHibernate/AR and does not know everything about them. So it's very hard for me.

Comment: @afsharm: no need to be a master or know everything (nobody does). Anyone can tackle this task.

Comment: you giving hope to me! May try this soon. Is there any guidance or information about it?

Comment: @afsharm: just drop the NH3 dll, make it compile, see failing tests, etc.